# Phantomjs not working in server to take screenshot

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I am using Phantomjs to create screenshot of a website. When i tested it in my localhost, it is working perfectly. But when i uploaded it to my server, it is showing blank while taking screenshot. I tested it in Windows. But my server in Linux. Is that the problem??

http://huzup.com/screenshot/

The files in it are index.php, shot.php, bin/phantomjs

I got the code from https://github.com/microweber/screen

Comment: Yeah now it worked. I changed the permissions